# Temperature Limits of an E ink Display?

Tags: temperature, heat, e-ink

I'm playing around with E-ink displays and I have a project in mind that would have to subject the display to extremely high temperatures (around 110 degrees Celsius). The display does not have to be operational during exposure but afterwards should hopefully operate.

My question is what would happen to it in theses temperatures? I couldn't find anything online other than that it's operating temps are from 0-50 degrees but I'm more interested in it's limits before it gets damaged. Would it react similarly to how an LCD would react? Will the display it self start to melt, pixels evaporate? I have no clue but any ideas would be really helpful, thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't buy any that don't have a decent datasheet. What does the datasheet say?

Comment: There was a datasheet but I couldn't find anything about a specific temperature threshold with which permanent damage would occur if exceeded. Just a lot of details on a built in temperature sensor. https://www.waveshare.com/w/upload/5/5b/2.13inch_e-Paper_%28D%29_Datasheet.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all on page 40.

[image]

*Figure 1. From the datasheet.*

These show you the test method the manufacturer's quality system is using for testing and would be the minimum they will guarantee. If you go outside these specifications then you are on your own.

Comment: I saw this as well but I just assumed these are tests they performed that showed the display could operate within those extreme temperatures. I was more interested In at what point permanent damage would occur even not in operation.  I guess what your saying makes sense though, If I go beyond these temperatures I'm pretty much on my own. I really appreciate you taking the time to help and read through it though.